# How can i get my Json formate data in ajax success?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

Thank you to all of you to providing so much dedicated support

Today i am getting some issue regarding Json string, I am returning some value in json and try to retrieve in Ajax Success but i am not able to get value to the variable

```
 //Return the value from registration.aspx.cs page 
 [WebMethod]
public static string verifyAadhar(string aadharNum)
{

    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    //try
    //{

    context.Session["aadharNum"] = aadharNum;        
    string url = "http://localhost:3787/api/login/login?aadharID=908765478921";
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

    request.Method = "POST";
    /*Optional*/

    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; //"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                                                             ///*Optional*/
    string userId = "abc";
    string Passwd = "123456";        
    string RequestLink = context.Request.Url.Authority;

    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("" + userId + ":" + Passwd + "")));

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        //?aadharID = 908765478921
        string json = "{\"aadharID\":\"" + 908765478921 + "\"" +  "\"}";
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
    //try
    //{
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
        response.Close();
        sr.Close();        
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { jsonObject });        
    //}
    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{   
    //    return ex.Message.ToString();
    //}
}


 //Receiving data here in ajax success
 var verfAadhar = '{"aadharNum":"' + aadharNum + '"}';
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:28331/register/registration.aspx/verifyAadhar",
        data: verfAadhar,
        datatype: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            $("#fname").val(objData[4]);                
        },
        error: function ()
        { console.log('Check your credentials'); }
    });
```

Please tell me how can i get my all in success data are available like [name, fname, dob, gen, mob.

Comment: please provide full c# code for "verifyAadhar" method

Comment: First do a `console.log(objData)` and check your object. Then you can access to its properties with dot notation, like `objData.name`. Note that you can also access to its properties using an array notation, but using the name of the property, not an index. eg: `objData["name"]`.

Comment: On a sidenote: $.parseJSON() is depricated in jquery 3.0. So you might want to use JSON.parse(). http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Can you provide some example values for the json, so we can provide a better answer?

Comment: Use success: function (data) {
            
            $("#fname").val(data.fname]);                
        },

Comment: thank you for your reply guys have tried these all method objData.name but still issue are there, Check it have updated all details..

Comment: Data is coming in {"jsonObject":{"message":"success","error":false,"data":{"name":"ramdev","gen":"male","dd":"10","mm":"10","yy":"1995","fathername":"patanjali                                                                                                                                                                                               "}}}

Comment: Let's try to simplify this. Doing the request really doesn't matter for answering this. Just focus on what is done after making a successful request. What is the json the server returns after the request? You could get it with console.log(data). Also what kind of field is $("#fname")? It seems unlikely that you want to load data from a request to an input field. If you are trying to modify some element (other then an input or textarea) use .text() instead.

Comment: i am using your guide line #RMo and #VedTiwari also $("#fname").text(data.name); by this not showing in input or any variable also. This is the return data formate {"jsonObject":{"message":"success","error":false,"data":{"na‌​me":"ramdev","gen":"‌​male","dd":"10","mm"‌​:"10","yy":"1995","f‌​athername":"patanjal‌​i "}}}

Comment: Is this behavior that you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/149ttk2e/

Comment: Yes i want like this result but in mu scenario you can see {"jsonObject":{"message":"success","error":false,"data":{"name":"ramdev","gen":"male","dd":"10","mm":"10","yy":"1995","fathername":"patanjali                                                                                                                                                                                               "}}}    data is like this and whenever i am trying to get then it's showing undefined

Comment: This seems to be the entire reply you get from doing a request to a server. Are you 100% sure this is what you get from console.log(data) after "success:" in the ajax function? You are only supposed to get the {"na‌​me":"ramdev","gen":"‌​male","dd":"10","mm"‌​:"10","yy":"1995","f‌​athername":"patanjal‌​i "} loaded into the "data" variable after completing the request.

Comment: yes i am 100% sure that i am getting this formate data  {"jsonObject":{"message":"success","error":false,"data":{"na‌​me":"ramdev","gen":"‌​male","dd":"10","mm"‌​:"10","yy":"1995","f‌​athername":"patanjal‌​i "}}} after success: function (data) { alert(data.name);} error: function ()
            { console.log('Chech your details'); } BUT ALERT IS SHOWING UNDEFINED DATA so now what should i do...

Comment: Hmm I don't really know a lot about back-end stuff a.t.m.. But to me it sounds like something has gone wrong with the code on the server sending you the data. I'm afraid I can't help much with that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you guys have got my answer of question.

```
success: function (data) {
            var arr = eval("(" + data.d + ")");
            alert(arr.jsonObject.message + "," + arr.jsonObject.error);
            var fatharName = arr.jsonObject.data.fathername;
            alert(fatharName);
```

}

by using that the method i can get my values from json..